# Twitter API asatymic/twitter with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, api, twitter, laravel-8

I followed his readme and I have done composer dump-autoload a million times, but still I receive an error. Don't know what i am making wrong. I am trying to use v2 version of twitter api. Please help me anyone.

**In config/app.php:**

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Atymic\Twitter\ServiceProvider\LaravelServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [

    ...
    'Twitter'   => Atymic\Twitter\Facade\Twitter::class,
],
```

**In my controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Twitter;
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $tweets = Twitter::getUserTimeline([
            'screen_name' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'count'       => 10,
            'format'      => 'json'
        ]);

        dd($tweets);

        return view('home');
    }

    public function about() {
        return view('about');
    }
}
```

**But I am getting this error:**

> Error
> Call to undefined method Atymic\Twitter\Service\Accessor::getUserTimeline()

Comment: mention library version .so it help someone to answer

Comment: Thanks i have updated my question by adding version.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have to import facade

Instead of this

```
use Twitter;
```

Import this

```
use Atymic\Twitter\Facade\Twitter;
```

If you are using alias then run following command

```
php artisan config:clear

composer dump-autoload

php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have imported the same using alias. See my above config/app.php file code.

Comment: oaky.try once directly using facade.can you mention package version

Comment: @salmanahmad. have you tried importing directly facade which i mentioned.

Comment: My package version is "atymic/twitter": "^3.1".  I also tried by importing directly facade but still error is same.

Comment: i have tired but i dint get any such error,since i dont have api key so i got [215] Bad Authentication data.

Comment: What steps you have followed to set up the package because this is very strange. Don't understand what i am making wrong.

Comment: i havent added anythink in app,php .installed using composer then used facade.but after your coment i tried using alias also and then ran mentioned command .

Comment: I tried everything but still i am giving same error. Not sure where i am doing mistake. I am using Laravel 8.4 , "atymic/twitter" package version : 3.1 and twitter api version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Please look to the twitter api version which you have defined in the .env. you may need to use 1.1 and you are using v2

Comment: It's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

I think `getUserTimeLine` is available for version 1.1, and I think as the readme says you can use `userTweets` for v2